# creating sub folders in FTP Folder

Tags: c#, winforms

The code for selecting the date using date picker and displaying the message in message box.but what i need is instead of displaying the message in need to create sub folders in FTP Folder

```
 public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
                dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today;
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                DateTime iDate;
                iDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
                MessageBox.Show("Selected date is " + iDate);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Net;

private void CreateDirectoryFTP(string directory)
{
    string path = @"/" + directory;
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(FtpHost + path);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FtpUser, FtpPass);
    try
    {
       request.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //directory exists
    }
}
```